# Allow "my questions" to replace existing menu bar item

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I never ever click on "Users".  Why not allow me to replace it with a button to view my questions?

Comment: @RobertLongson this is about the iPhone app

Comment: Well you can rearrange the tab bar items any way you like so just adding a "my questions" item would be good, no need to replace anything as you can do that yourself.

Comment: @Cai you can re arrange it but you can't replace "Users" with "My Questions"